# heap overflow error when push vector<int> into a vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, algorithm

The code is supposed to calculate [pascal's triangle](https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/). 
Like

```
   1

 1   1

1    2   1 

1  3   3   1
    ...
```

However, when I run my code, it shows me heap overflow error:

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x604000000040 at pc 0x00000040634d bp 0x7fff26a50360 sp 0x7fff26a50358
```

The code I have is

```
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
    vector<vector<int>> triangle;
    if(numRows == 0)    return triangle;

    for(int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        vector<int> ithRow(i, 1);  //ith Row should have i numbers
        for(int j = 1; j < i - 1; j++) { //numbers other than first and last are calculated using two values from previous row
            ithRow.push_back(triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j]);
        }
        triangle.push_back(ithRow);
    }
    return triangle;
}
```

It works when I did not create a new variable to hold the new row.

```
public:
    vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
        vector<vector<int>> triangle;

        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            triangle.push_back(vector<int>(i+1,1));            
            for(auto j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                triangle[i][j] = triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
        return triangle;
    }
};
```

Can anyone please help me with this piece of code?

Comment: What is the number of rows that you use to call your function? Did you try to step through with the debugger?

Comment: When you find yourself running up against potential out of bounds indexing errors, consider using `std::vector::at` instead of `[]`. `at` performs a bounds check and throws an exception. You can catch the exception an print out your `i` and `j` values` or just take a peek at them with your friendly neighborhood debugger. Once you have found the mistake (or proved that there isn't one) you can switch back to `[]`

Comment: *I don't think I access any out of range value* -- Don't write programs thinking this way.  All that will happen is you potentially miss out on errors because you are so sure you are not making mistakes.  `triangle.at(i - 1).at(j - 1) + triangle.at(i - 1).at(j);`  Try that, and don't be surprised when an `out_of_range` exception is thrown.

Comment: you're creating `ithRow` with `i` ones but then you push another `i - 2` values instead of setting them in-place

Answer (score 4):

The earliest your code gets to the body of the inner `j` loop is when `i == 3`.  At that point, you've pushed two rows into `triangle` (one when `i == 1` and one when `i == 2`).  You then try to access `triangle[i - 1][j - 1]`, which will try to access `triangle[2]`.  Since there are only two entries in the vector, this access outside of the bounds of the vector, resulting in Undefined Behavior (your crash).

Since `vector[i - 1]` is being constructed in `ithRow`, just use that variable instead.  You don't need to `push_back` since you've already added `i` elements to `ithRow`.

Comment: That is very true! I was thinking 3rd row should use 2nd row from the triangle, but that is actually triangle[1] not triangle[2].  The explanation is very clear. Thank you so much!